# Trouble in understanding the bitwise operators left and right shift function in programming

Tags: c

In ANSI C section 2.9, the bitwise operators, I am unable to understand this particular code.

I know how each bitwise operator works, but combinations need some help.

```
getbits(x, 4, 3)

unsigned getbits(unsigned x, int p, int n) {
    return (x >> (p + 1 - n)) & ~(~0 << n);
}
```

Comment: If you know how each bitwise operator works, I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I believe it's about the function itself, which we have to admit apart from the name couldn't be more cryptic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`~0`  is an `int` made of binary ones (`111...111111`)
`~0<<n`  introduces `n` zeros in the lower bits (`111...111000`).
`~(~0<<n)` flips the bits (`000...000111`)
`x>>(p+1-n)` shifts `x` towards the lower bits (`00XXX...XXXXXX`).
The `&` operation combines the previous two results: upper zeros are kept as zeros and the lower `X` bits (facing the ones) are kept as is (`00000...000XXX`).

Thus this function retrieves a `n`-bit pattern of `x` from bit `p`, but shifted `(p+1-n)` positions towards lower bits (ie, placed at the lower position).

Answer (score 2):

The function is supposed to extract a bitfield of width `n` at position `p`.

There are problems in this function:

- `p + 1 - n` seems bogus but it is the number of bits to the right of the bitfield if `p` is the bit number of the most significant bit in the bitfield, numbered from `0` for the least significant bit..
- the code has implementation defined behavior if the most significant bit of `x` is included in the bitfield because `0` is a signed integer. `0U` should be used instead.
- the code does not work to extract a bitfield that has the full width of `unsigned int`, because shifting by a number of bits greater or equal to the width of the type has undefined behavior. The shift should be split in 2 parts, `n - 1` bits and an additional 1 bit. `n - 1` will be in the range `[0..31]` so the variable shift is fully defined.

Here is a more portable version:

```
// extract `n` bits at position `p`. n in [1..32], p in `[1..32]`
unsigned getbits(unsigned x, int p, int n) {
   return (x >> (p + 1 - n)) & ~(~0U << (n - 1) << 1);
}
```

Here are the steps:

- `0U` is the unsigned int null constant.
- `~0U` has all its value bits set.
- `~0 << (n - 1)` has all its value bits set except for the `n - 1` low order bits, which are cleared.
- `~0 << (n - 1) << 1` has all its value bits set except for the `n` low order bits, which are cleared.
- `~(~0 << (n - 1) << 1)` has the `n` low order bits set.
- `p + 1 - n` is the number of bits with lower order than the bitfield
- `x >> (p + 1 - n)` shifts the value to the right, leaving the bitfield in the low order bit positions.
- `(x >> (p + 1 - n)) & ~(~0 << (n - 1) << 1)` masks the higher order bits, leaving just the bitfield value.

Note that there are other ways to compute the mask:

```
~0U >> (sizeof(unsigned) * CHAR_BIT - n)

(1U << (n - 1) << 1) - 1
```

Comment: You should add the explanation that the left shift for the mask is split into `<< (n - 1)` and `<< 1` instead of using a single `<< n` because it would be undefined behavior if `n` was equal to the width of `unsigned`. I think this is not obvious.

Comment: `p - 1 - n` will require a minimum of `p == 2` (together with `n == 1`); smaller `p` will result in negative bit shift. Original version seems to be correct in this respect, consider, consider `getbits(n, 0, 1)`. `p` is not the least, but most significant bit to be used. If `p` was least significant bit, we could just shift by `p`.

Comment: I agree with `0u` but I cannot understand your reasoning about the 1 based bit numbering. As far as I understand it, the OP's version is 0 based. For example with `x=4+8+16`, `p=4` and `n=3` we obtain `7` which seems correct to me.

Comment: @Aconcagua: indeed, foolish of me, I would personally always specify the bit offset, instead of the most significant bit number. The bits numbers are 0 based as prog-fh commented. Answer amended.

Comment: I would have been very surprised if K&R were wrong ;^)